# Setting response of page from client side of 404 on showing the page with strapi CMS

Tags: next.js, strapi

I am working with Strapi CMS and Next.js on showing page from strapi cms need to change the status code to 404 on the browser network window

Whenever a person enters unknown page where data is not found on CMS. Need to redirect it to error page and gave 404 error response in the browser network console.

[The response from browser status code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyBMX.png)

[Page on the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbNuG.jpg)

Here is my pages.tsx file from where checking if any data is present at CMS level for that url.

```
export default async function PageRoute({ params }: Props) {
    let page:any;
    let isError:boolean=false;
     page = await getPageBySlug(params.slug, params.lang);
    if (!page || page.data === null || page.data.length === 0) {
        isError=true;
            //return null;
        page = await getPageBySlug("error", params.lang);
        console.log('Page data sections',page.data[0].attributes.contentSections);
    }
    const contentSections = page.data[0].attributes.contentSections;
    return contentSections.map((section: any, index: number) => sectionRenderer(section, index,isError));
}
```

I have tried on the component level redirect on the error page with status 404

```
const InnerHero = ({ data,isError }: any) => {
  console.log('I am inside Ineer Hero',isError);
  debugger;
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add(`hero-inner-navbar`);
console.log('I am inside client side Inner Hero component',isError);
   if (isError) {

   }
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {data.TypeOfHero === "L2" ? <InnerHeroSimple data={data} /> : null}
      {data.TypeOfHero === "L3" ? <InnerHeroOverlay data={data} /> : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default InnerHero;
```

Also from the middleware level

```
    async function SetResponseCode(request:NextRequest,response:NextResponse) {
       let Header=request?.nextUrl.toString().split('/');
       if(Header && Header.length == 5){
       const lang= Header[3];
       const slug= Header[4];
       let page:any;
        page =await  getPageBySlug(slug as string, lang as string);
        if (page.data.length !==0 ) return NextResponse.next();
             page =await  getPageBySlug("error" as string, lang as string);
              const contentSections = page.data[0].attributes.contentSections;

             
               response.headers.set("status","404");
               response.headers.set("statusText","Page Not Found");
               response.headers.set("statusCode","404");
               request.headers.set("statusCode","404");

             // //  request.headers.set("Status Code","404");
            // //  request.headers.set("statusText","Page Not Found");

               console.log('response status',request.headers.get('statusCode'));
               console.log('rerequest status',response.headers.get('statusCode'));
               // const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
               // url.pathname = `/error`;
               return contentSections.map((section: any, index: number) => sectionRenderer(section, index));
           }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`notFound`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/not-found#notfound) from `next/navigation`. This will automatically throw a 404 error and render your [`not-found.tsx`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found) file (if you have one), or the default 404 page of Next.js

```
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

export default async function PageRoute({ params }: Props) {
  let page: any;
  let isError: boolean = false;
  page = await getPageBySlug(params.slug, params.lang);
  if (!page || page.data === null || page.data.length === 0) {
    notFound();
  }
  const contentSections = page.data[0].attributes.contentSections;
  return contentSections.map((section: any, index: number) =>
    sectionRenderer(section, index, isError)
  );
}
```

Comment: i have tried this i want to change the status response code in the network tab it shows 200 okaey there is a separate ticket for this
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51021